# Lists of Ukrainian words by language of origin / Статистика походження слів в української мови

Tags: запозичені-слова

I want look statistic of modern Ukrainian words derived from each language group.

I tried look for this, but I can't find. I met only this resources:

- [For the English language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin)
- [When and from where the Ukrainian language borrowed words with some examples.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96)

---

Є бажання поглянути на приблизні статистичні дані, що складаються з процентів чи кількості, походження слів у сучасній українській мові.

Я намагався віднайти це, але ніяк не вдається. Натомість я натрапив на:

- [Для англійської мови](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_English_words_by_country_or_language_of_origin)
- [Коли й звідки були запозичення з деякими прикладами](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96)

Answer (score 8):

You can find some information here: [Словник іншомовних слів](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/ures/book/index.shtml). See section *[За мовами походження](https://www.jnsm.com.ua/sis/pro.shtml#)*.

### Про словник

> Тлумачний словник іншомовних слів містить науково-популярне пояснення
> слів чужомовного походження з наведенням їх українського відповідника
> і синонімічного ряду.
>
> Наразі у «Словнику» 20293 статті, котрі охоплюють термінологію з
> найрізноманітніших сфер. Усі словникові статті містять етимологічну
> довідку (див. список скорочень) і вказівку на область застосування чи
> вживання терміну. Ви можете переглянути статті «Словника» в
> [алфавітному порядку](http://www.jnsm.com.ua/cgi-bin/u/book/sis.pl?action=alpha), за мовою походження або знайти тлумачення певного
> терміну через форму запиту.